# How to fix exception message - 'Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream' in .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, xmlhttprequest, httpwebrequest, webrequest

Getting Error exception message - 'Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream', I am using .Net 4.5.2, C#

Below is the code -

```
HttpWebRequest request = null; request = WebRequest.Create("https://msedgedriver.azureedge.net") as HttpWebRequest;

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = ServicePointManager.DefaultPersistentConnectionLimit;

((HttpWebRequest)request).KeepAlive = false;


// Error received at line below -  
HttpWebResponse response =  request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

I can read response XML on postman and browser, but above code is giving exception - ' The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.' with InnerException as  'Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream'

Please advise

Comment: You should remove TLS 1.0 and 1.1 which is not longer being accepted by servers from your client code.  How long does it take for exception to occur?  If it is 30 seconds you may be going out to a proxy and you may need to set proxy to null (request.Proxy = null).  Net 4.5.2 may not be supporting TLS 1.3 and that may need to be removed also.

Comment: @jdweng, It takes less than 10 seconds for exception to occur. However, I have removed TLS 1.0  and 1.1, but exception is still occurring.

Comment: Remove SSl3 also.  It is no longer used.  It didn't look closely before and thought SSL3 was TLS3.

Comment: @jdweng, I removed SSL3, yet same exception and then also removed last TLS1.2, same exemption still exists.

Comment: Either the certificate is not loaded properly, the certificate encryption mode isn't compatible with TLS 1.2 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security), or you need the hot patches on following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls